# how to assign different output to different variables in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables

I wrote this code to iterate over variables and add output to it, it is working fine while iterate over numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=100
y=200

app_test () {
    ((x++))
}

for app in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0; do
    app_test
        x[app]="${x}"
done

echo ${x[1]}
echo ${x[2]}
echo ${x[3]}
echo ${x[4]}
echo ${x[5]}
echo ${x[6]}
echo ${x[7]}
echo ${x[8]}
echo ${x[9]}
echo ${x[0]}
```

output:

```
$ 101
  102
  103
  104
  105
  106
  107
  108
  109
  110
```

But when I use words instead of number like "foo bar" it doesn't work and also add last value of number variable to name variables

```
#!/bin/bash

x=100
y=200

app_test () {
    ((x++))
}

for app in foo bar 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0; do
    app_test
    x[app]="${x}"
done

echo ${x[foo]}
echo ${x[bar]}
echo ${x[3]}
echo ${x[4]}
echo ${x[5]}
echo ${x[6]}
echo ${x[7]}
echo ${x[8]}
echo ${x[9]}
echo ${x[0]}
```

output:

```
$ 110
  110
  103
  104
  105
  106
  107
  108
  109
  110
```

can anyone help me to fix my code and also explain why so I doesn't make mistake in the future

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Your presented output does not match your code. Are you sure you executed your code?

Answer (score 2):

A few issues with the current code:

- for non-numeric array indices the array must be declared as an associative array (`declare -A`)
- in `x[app]="${x}"` the array index should be referenced as `$app` [see KamilCuk's answer for an explanation of why `x[app]` is processed as `x[0]`]
- while the dual use of `x` as a scalar and an array appears to work, `x=100` and `x++` are the same as `x[0]=100` and `x[0]++`; net result is the code works (in this case) but could lead to confusion; to eliminate any confusion I would use a different name for the array

Updating OP's current code to address these issues:

```
x=100
y=200

app_test () {
    ((x++))
}

unset arr
declare -A arr                               # declare array 'arr[]' as an 'A'ssociative array

for app in foo bar 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0; do
    app_test
    arr[$app]="${x}" 
done

typeset -p arr                               # display structure/contents of array 'arr[]'

echo ${arr[foo]}
echo ${arr[bar]}
echo ${arr[3]}
echo ${arr[4]}
echo ${arr[5]}
echo ${arr[6]}
echo ${arr[7]}
echo ${arr[8]}
echo ${arr[9]}
echo ${arr[0]}                               # same as ${arr}

echo ${arr}                                  # same as ${arr[0]}
```

This generates:

```
declare -A arr=([bar]="102" [foo]="101" [0]="110" [3]="103" [4]="104" [5]="105" [6]="106" [7]="107" [8]="108" [9]="109" )

101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110                                          # ${arr[0]}

110                                          # ${arr}
```

Answer (score 1):

> can any one explain why

- "Normal" (i.e. non-associative) arrays are indexed with *numbers*.

  - Opposed to associative arrays which are indexed with strings.
- The expression inside `[` `]` of a normal array is interpreted as an arithmetic expression.
- Inside an *arithmetic* context an undefined variable is assumed to be zero.

  ```
  $ echo $((some_undefined_variable))
  0
  ```
- In your code `foo` and `bar` are not defined as variables.
- Because of all that, `echo ${x[foo]}` is the same as `echo ${x[0]}`.

Comment: So how do i fix

Answer (score 1):

By default, arrays in bash are indexed by integers. If you want to index them using strings, you'll have to use an associative array, which is done using

```
declare -A NAME
```

Where NAME is the name of the associative array.

I've renamed the array to `z`, just so it doesn't conflict with `x`, which you've already used. Not necessary, but I think it's clearer.

The declaration is `declare -A z`. Note that I also changed `z[app]="${x}"` to `z[$app]="${x}"`, which is necessary because `app` is no longer numeric.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

x=100
y=200

app_test () {
    ((x++))
}

declare -A z

for app in foo bar 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0; do
    app_test
    z[$app]="${x}"
done

echo ${z[1]}
echo ${z[2]}
echo ${z[3]}
echo ${z[4]}
echo ${z[5]}
echo ${z[6]}
echo ${z[7]}
echo ${z[8]}
echo ${z[9]}
echo ${z[0]}
```